# Finding the Significance and T Test of the below data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, significant-figures

I am trying to solve this question below since a few hours now but cannot wrap my head around it: [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ycn.png)

> The following information was obtained related to the sales of a product in two shops in Delhi and Mumbai:
> \begin{array}{l|l|l|l}\text{Delhi}&\bar{x}=3.5&\sum x=40&\sum x^2=275&n_1=12\\\hline\text{Mumbai}&\bar{y}=5&\sum y=48&\sum y^2=235&n_2=10\end{array}
> Is there a evidence of significant difference in the sales in Delhi and Mumbai? Test at 5% level of significance. (Use $t_{0.05}=2.086$ at $V=20$)

I am having trouble finding the Standard Deviation of the sample. Since the formula for finding the same requires the data points themselves, not the sum of all the data points, it is not possible (according to me) to find the Standard Deviation.

**What I have tried:** 
I have tried substituting the value of (∑(x^2) - x̄) in the formula for standard deviation but to no avail.

**The issue I am encountering:** 
How can I find the standard deviation of the samples? I have everything I need to find the t value of the samples except the standard deviation of the samples.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi! Well I have tried a few ways to put things into perspective by directly substituting difference of sum of x and mean of the sample in the formula to find standard deviation but all in vain... I am at my wits end on now...

Comment: Could you edit your post to include what you have tried, where you are stuck. [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) could help.

Comment: Done. I have edited the post to be clearer

Comment: Is this the formula you are looking for? $\sigma = \sqrt{\left(\frac1n\sum x_i^2\right) - \left(\frac1n\sum x_i\right)^2}$

Comment: Oh yea that seems the formula I need to use! Weird thing, that isn't available in my book... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I typeset your question, since it is better than a picture. Could you verify that everything is correct.

Comment: Seems all good. Thanks for that! Sorry, still new to this website, I don't have much experience with LaTeX and all